# C Visual 2008 is trying to include libraries for linux outside ifdef

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, include, libraries, platform

I'm kind of really new to this cross platform thing and to say the least I kind of hate dealing with windows but I have to for uni :(

Anyway, I have almost everything I want working on linux and windows but I'm trying to combine them and having one program.
I have searched for a bit for this but I can't find a solution. Here is what I have-

```
#ifdef WIN32

#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

#else

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
void killMe();

#endif
```

Visual studio tries to 'include' sys/socket and this doesn't exist for windows. I'm hoping there is a simple solution to achieving this.
It works all well if I just comment it out and I know WIN32 is defined as I use a printf() to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro is `_WIN32` (leading underscore), not `WIN32`:

```
#ifdef _WIN32

#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

#else

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
void killMe();

#endif
```

See [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

---

The macro `WIN32` is `#define`d in the header file `WinDef.h` (at line 31). This would explain why `WIN32` was available in your `.c` source and not in the `.h` as the header `windows.h` includes `WinDef.h` and (presumably) your `.c` file includes your header file.

Comment: That works now. But why does WIN32 work in my program code but not in my header file (from what i've gathered)? Visual even greys out the code inside the 'else' condition.

Comment: Thanks alot. I find it so hard to find information about c in win32 as it's either way too basic or extremely complicated.
Thanks again.